# Is it possible to run Virtual PC on Windows 2008 Web 64 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possible to run the free edition of Virtual PC on Windows 2008 Web 64 bit

Also does Web Server come with DNS?

Answer (score 1):

The free product 'Virtual PC 2007 Service Pack 1' is supported on Windows Server 2008 Standard edition, so although not fully supported by the Web edition I doubt you'd have any issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not supported by Microsoft.  But Virtual Server 2005 would work, and that's nearly the same thing as Virtual PC.  It's even a free download.